# How do I avoid symlinks using an Ant FileSet?

Tags: ant, symlink, fileset

I have a directory tree that includes a symlink to . (the current directory). When I attempt to iterate over this using an Ant FileSet, I get the following error:

```
Caught error while checking for symbolic links
 at org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner.causesIllegalSymlinkLoop(DirectoryScanner.java:1859)
```

The code that I am using to generate the scanner is:

```
FileSet files = new FileSet();
Project project = new Project();
project.setBasedir( dir );
files.setProject( project );
files.setDir( project.getBaseDir() );

files.getDirectoryScanner().setFollowSymlinks( false );

for( Iterator iter = files.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `followsymlinks` property of `FileSet` to `false` as [documented here.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the 'not-follow' in the wrong place.  Use

```
files.setFollowSymlinks( false );
```

instead of

```
files.getDirectoryScanner().setFollowSymlinks( false );
```

The code you posted will set 'not-follow symlinks' only when scanning *below* the top-level directory of the fileset.  Symlinks in the top-level directory will still be followed.

Its not clear from what you have posted precisely what's causing an IOException to be raised in the `causesIllegalSymlinkLoop()` method (that exception is being caught at line 1859).
But if you set not-follow on the fileset rather than its internal directory scanner, the method will not be called at all.

Comment: If you're brought here after searching for a way to not follow symlinks, then this is not for you. setFollowSymlinks is completely misleading, it ignores symlinks altogether. What I was looking for is a way to not include the set of files/directories that the symlink points to in the set, which this does not do.